# can't find executable installation file in droid explorer folder so how do I install on windows 10 please

Tags: installation, droid-explorer

I am new to droid explorer, I wish to install it on my windows 10 system
I downloaded the software from this link https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer.
I need a step by step guide on how to install the software itself as I can't find an executable installation file.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub is mainly for developers, therefore the main view shows the source code repository. On GitHub the binary files are usually available in the "releases" section of each project.

https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/releases

In this page you can finde the ZIPed version of the DroidExplorer installer.